# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fs.readdir is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filesystems, fs

I'm building a system where it lists all the icons I have stored in a folder. I downloaded the entire material-icons and it is in my svg folder. Inside my svg folder contains other icons that are not in the directories. First I tried just using `fs` but that didn't work. Then I used a module called `list-react-files` but that also threw an error.

```js
function listDirectories(path) {
    const dir = [];
    ListReactFiles(path).then(function (files) {
        Array.from(files).forEach(function (elem) {
            if (fs.lstatSync(elem).isDirectory() == true) dir.push(elem);
        });
    });

    return dir;
} 

listDirectories("./assets/icons/svg/");
```

Error

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fs.readdir is not a function
```

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv0c5.png)

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run this code against your node environment?

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir('.', function(err, files) {
    console.log(files);
});
```

Comment: This leads me to speculate a problem with your node installation.

Comment: I am running Node v12.18.4 (installed on Ubuntu 18.04) with create-react-app version 4.0.1